# Overall size of UIView when clipsToBounds = false

Tags: ios, uiview, size

I have a `UIView *view` with its `view.clipsToBounds = false`. I have added subviews to it whose frames extend beyond the visible bounds of the `view`.

My question now is how to get the overall size of the `view`, including the extended subviews?

Comment: What do you mean by size, do you need area?

Comment: what you want to achieve ? And default value of `clipsToBounds` is `false` or  `NO`. So you not need to set `false` because it is already!

Comment: @NikhilManapure I mean the overall CGSize of the `view`, which includes the size of the subviews which have extended beyond the `view`'s visible bounds.

Comment: CGSize has height and width, how are you expecting it to give you size of a non-rectangular view.

Comment: What I am trying to do is take a snapshot of the said `view`, thats why I need the size.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to understand why you want size of view including its subviews, but you can get it by looping through all subviews and applying simple calculations as following:

```
float x = 0, y = 0, endX = 0, endY = 0;

for (UIView *vw in yourview.subviews)
{
    CGRect rct = vw.frame;

    if(rct.origin.x < x)
        x = rct.origin.x;
    if(rct.origin.y < y)
        y = rct.origin.y;

    if(rct.size.width+rct.origin.x > endX)
        endX = rct.size.width + rct.origin.x;

    if(rct.size.height + rct.origin.y > endY)
        endY = rct.size.height + rct.origin.y;

}
```